# Multiple left joins not working with subquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I know a question similar to this already has been posted but I can't find the problem with my sql query with trying out things found on google

The error I am getting is 'You have an error in your SQL syntax'

Here is my code

```
select 
    campaigns.campaign_name,
    calls.count,
    first.count as first,
    second.count as second,
    third.count as third,
    fourth.count as fourth,
    fifth.count as fifth,
    sixth.count as sixth
    from campaigns
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        select count(*) as count, campaign_id FROM calls where direction = 'Incoming' group by campaign_id
    ) as calls
    ON campaigns.id = calls.campaign_id
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        select count(*) as count, 
        campaign_id FROM calls 
        where direction = 'Incoming' 
        AND DATE(created_at) BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2016-01-01'
        group by campaign_id
    ) as first
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        select count(*) as count, 
        campaign_id FROM calls 
        where direction = 'Incoming' 
        AND DATE(created_at) BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2016-01-01'
        group by campaign_id
    ) as second
    ON campaigns.id = second.campaign_id
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        select count(*) as count, 
        campaign_id FROM calls 
        where direction = 'Incoming' 
        AND DATE(created_at) BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2016-01-01'
        group by campaign_id
    ) as third
    ON campaigns.id = third.campaign_id
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        select count(*) as count, 
        campaign_id FROM calls 
        where direction = 'Incoming' 
        AND DATE(created_at) BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2016-01-01'
        group by campaign_id
    ) as fourth
    ON campaigns.id = fourth.campaign_id
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        select count(*) as count, 
        campaign_id FROM calls 
        where direction = 'Incoming' 
        AND DATE(created_at) BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2016-01-01'
        group by campaign_id
    ) as fifth
    ON campaigns.id = fifth.campaign_id
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        select count(*) as count, 
        campaign_id FROM calls 
        where direction = 'Incoming' 
        AND DATE(created_at) BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2016-01-01'
        group by campaign_id
    ) as sixth
    ON sixth.campaign_id = campaigns.id
    group by campaigns.id
```

The error seems to be at line 69
The last second line of the sql query `ON sixth.campaign_id = campaigns.id`

Comment: Missing ON clause after "first". Redundant GROUP BY, since the counts have already been done in the sub-queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to have such a complicated query.  Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select c.campaign_name,
       sum(direction = 'Incoming') as cnt,
       sum(direction = 'Incoming' and DATE(created_at) BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2016-01-01') as first,
       . . .
from campaigns c left join
     calls
     on c.campaign_id = calls.campaign_id
group by c.campaign_name;
```

All your conditions appear to be the same, but you can add additional `sum()`s for other conditions.

Comment: BETWEEN dates would change with each join can I still work it out?

Comment: @Muhammad Probably not because that wasnt the question you made.

Comment: Yes the between dates could be modified for each conditional as @Gordon has demonstrated.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes jarlh found the problem with code but as he answered it in comment I can't mark it as answer I think but I was interested in how I can shorten the query so asked the question from Gordon - Thanks

Comment: @Muhammad You just need repeat the `SUM ... `  with different between. this is the way to go.Gordon just show you the `first`. Just do the same for all others

Comment: @Muhammad . . . Yes.  I only added the first condition, because the conditions are the same in all your subqueries.  It doesn't make sense to repeat the conditions either in the answer or in the original subqueries.  You can readily add more `sum()`s with different conditions to get what you want.